# In R/Shiny positioning ggplots chart in specifics places after select input choice

Tags: r, shiny

My main chart come from the select input and it is displayed at `plotOutput('chart_1')`

After this the country that was chosen on SelectInput is removed from the checkbox input and then the user should choose only 3 charts that will be placed at `plotOutput('chart_2')`,`plotOutput('chart_3')`,`plotOutput('chart_4')`

In other words: If I chose at selectInput 'Brazil' I will only have 5 options to include at positions `plotOutput('chart_2')`,`plotOutput('chart_3')`,`plotOutput('chart_4')`, and 'Brazil" will no longer be avaiable at checkbox input widgets.

My problem is that I am not be abl to set correctly thi idea with `awesomeCheckboxGroup`widgets and include the other 3 charts tha the user will choose. This is what Ive done so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(shinyWidgets)

gapminder_df <-
  gapminder %>% filter(country %in% c("Brazil", "Chile", "Argentina", "Peru")) %>%
  group_split(country)


chart1 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[1]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'red')
chart2 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[2]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'green')
chart3 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[3]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'blue')
chart4 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[4]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'black')
chart5 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[4]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'black')
chart6 <-
  ggplot(gapminder_df[[4]], aes(x = year, y = country)) + geom_line(color =  'black')


all_countries <-
  c("Brazil", "Chile", "Argentina", "Peru", "Uganda", "Turkey")
names(all_countries) <-
  c("Brazil", "Chile", "Argentina", "Peru", "Uganda", "Turkey")


chart_list <-
  list(chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5, chart6) %>% setNames(all_countries)




ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = 'country',
    choices = all_countries,
    label = "Paises"
  ),
  
  awesomeCheckboxGroup(
    inputId = "countries_check",
    label = "Checkboxes",
    choices = all_countries 
  ),
  div(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput('chart_1', height = '400px')),
    column(
      width = 6,
      plotOutput('chart_2'),
      plotOutput('chart_3'),
      plotOutput('chart_4')
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$chart_1 <- renderPlot({
    chart_list[[input$country]]
    
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$country,
  #              
  #              {
  #                if (input$country == input$countries_check) {
  #                  awesomeCheckboxGroup(
  #                    label = "Checkboxes",
  #                    inputId = "countries_check",
  #                    choices = input$country[-1]
  #                  )
  #                }
                 
              output$chart_2 <- renderPlot({
               chart_list[[input$countries_check[1]]]
             })
             output$chart_3 <- renderPlot({
               chart_list[[input$countries_check[2]]]
             })
             output$chart_4 <- renderPlot({
               chart_list[[input$countries_check[3]]]
             })
             
                 
                 
               # })
  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by updating your checkbox input using an `observeEvent`. To this end I set the choices to `NULL` in the UI then inside the `observeEvent` use `updateAwesomeCheckboxGroup` to update or set the available choices excluding the selected country:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "country",
    choices = all_countries,
    label = "Paises"
  ),
  awesomeCheckboxGroup(
    inputId = "countries_check",
    label = "Checkboxes",
    choices = NULL
  ),
  div(
    column(
      width = 6,
      plotOutput("chart_1", height = "400px")
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      plotOutput("chart_2"),
      plotOutput("chart_3"),
      plotOutput("chart_4")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart_1 <- renderPlot({
    chart_list[[input$country]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$country, {
    updateAwesomeCheckboxGroup(
      session = session,
      inputId = "countries_check",
      choices = all_countries[!all_countries == input$country]
    )
  })

  n_countries_checked <- reactive({
    length(input$countries_check)
  })
  
  output$chart_2 <- renderPlot({
    req(n_countries_checked() > 0)
    chart_list[[input$countries_check[[1]]]]
  })
  output$chart_3 <- renderPlot({
    req(n_countries_checked() > 1)
    chart_list[[input$countries_check[[2]]]]
  })
  output$chart_4 <- renderPlot({
    req(n_countries_checked() > 2)
    chart_list[[input$countries_check[[3]]]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I just made an edit to include a possible approach to connect the charts to the checkbox. Tricky part is to account for the number of checked countries. And of course will the code only display the first three checked counters even if the user checks more than that. Haven't found to set a max value.